# Invalid attempt to read when Reader is closed - MySqlDataReader C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, mysqldatareader

Getting an `Invalid attempt to read when Reader is closed` exception in my `duplicateNameCheck` method, when attempting to read from the DataReader. I'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public static MySqlConnection GetSqlConnection() {
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    return connection;
}

public static MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string sqlQuery, MySqlConnection connection) {
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)) {     
        try {
            connection.Open();                                      
            MySqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();    

             return sqlReader;                                       
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                            
             return null;                                            
         }
    }
}

public static bool duplicateNameCheck(string inName) {
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Account";    

    using (MySqlDataReader sqlReader = SQLHelper.ExecuteReader(sqlQuery, SQLHelper.GetSqlConnection())) {

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {                     
            if (inName.Equals(sqlReader[1].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {  
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;                                       
}
```

Comment: Don't catch an exception in `SQLHelper.ExecuteReader()` and return null. You're pretending, in that case, that the whole thing didn't totally fail. But it did. It utterly failed, and the caller is not getting back a SqlDataReader. That's what exceptions are for. Maybe the catch belongs in `duplicateNameCheck()`, maybe in its caller. But not where it is. Considering glenebob's valid and important point, the whole helper thing seems pointless. What is all the `MySql*` stuff about?

Comment: When `MySqlCommand` is disposed (before the using block exits), the reader is also disposed because the `MySqlCommand` created it. When the reader is disposed, it is also closed. I am not sure if the connection is still open or close; because the connection object is created outside, it should not be closed (would be interesting to test and find out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're disposing the SqlCommand before attempting to use the SqlReader it produced. They'll both need to stay open until you're done with the reader.

Comment: You should probably explain what `using` does.

Comment: Thought I knew what `using` did, it worked fine when I was using `Sql` instead of `MySql`, which is something I had to switch it to.

Comment: You're using it right, it's just that the Command disposes the Reader when it gets closed (disposed), which isn't entirely intuitive.

Comment: I understood what he meant, fixed it, and it's working now.

Comment: @user9405863, nope ... that's an quiet sufficient answer